# handling callbacks in node

Tags: node.js, callback

I'm still learning node programming....I'm building a web app using express and want to wrap my head around event-based non-blocking I/O with respect to nesting callbacks from other functions inside other callbacks.

Here is one issue that I am trying to understand with respect to using callbacks everywhere:

I cannot just do this in  most cases (crypo will allow this method to work sync so this example is ok):

```
user.reset_password_token = require('crypto').randomBytes(32).toString('hex');
```

I was having to go about doing this before I saw that the above example works:

```
User.findOne({ email: req.body.username }, function(err, user) {

  crypto.randomBytes(256, function(ex, buf) {
    if (ex) throw ex;
    user.reset_password_token = buf.toString('hex');
  });

  user.save(); // can I do this here?

  //will user.reset_password_token be set here??
  // Or do I need to put all this code into the randomBytes callback...
  //Can I continue programming the .findOne() callback here
    // with the expectation that
  //user.reset_password_token is set?
  //Or am I out of bounds...for the crypto callback to have been called reliably.
});
```

If I call user.save() after the randomBytes code (not inside it's callback) will the token always be set?

Answer (score 1):

```
//will user.reset_password_token be set here?
```

No. In the example you have, the call to `crypto` is done asynchronously which means that execution will not stop to let that call finish and will instead continue executing code within your `findOne` method.

```
User.findOne({ email: req.body.username }, function(err, user) {

  crypto.randomBytes(256, function(ex, buf) {
    if (ex) throw ex;
    user.reset_password_token = buf.toString('hex');

    // only within this scope will user.reset_password_token be
    // set as expected
    user.save();
  });

  // undefined since this code is called before the crypto call completes
  // (at least when you call crypto async like you have)
  console.log(user.reset_password_token);
});
```

Comment: Could you please describe the right way to handel such a situation? (that is, in case of a function that does not allow synchronous behaviour as randomBytes).